# How to source a bash-script within tcl (expect)

Tags: shell, proxy, tcl, expect

I want to set an http proxy within the bash environment `(export http_proxy=xyz)`. So I added the command to the end of the `.bash_profile` and called

```
exec /bin/sh -c "source /path/to/.bash_profile"
```

But it does not work like expected: `$::env(http_proxy)` does not exist (but there is no typo).
I also tried to run the script like that: `exec /bin/sh -c [exec cat /path/to/.bash_profile]` .. but with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying

```
exec /bin/sh -c "source /path/to/.bash_profile"
```

would `source` the `/path/to/.bash_profile` in a subshell.  So any changes made to the environment are effectively ignored when the command is done executing.

In order to pass an environment variable to a program, try:

```
exec /usr/bin/env http_proxy=xyz program
```

Comment: Or: `set env(http_proxy) xyz; exec program`

Comment: Or start a new bash login shell after modifying `~/.bash_profile`. It will source it for you. Then start expect from that shell.